# Files not getting stored in correct folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have a form in CodeIgniter that allows the user to upload 2 separate files. At the backend I want these files to get stored in the different folder. In the controller i have written the upload code

```
public function upload()
    {
        /**Start uploading file**/
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/file/.';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
            {
              $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
              echo $error;

            }
        else
            {
              $data = $this->upload->data();
              echo $file = $data['file_name']; //name of  file

            }

        /**End uploading file**/

        /**Start uploading img**/

        $config2['upload_path'] = './assets/img/.';
        $config2['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
        $config2['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
        $config2['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config2);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('img')) 
            {
              $error1 = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
              echo $error1;

            }
        else
            {
              $data1 = $this->upload->data();
              echo $img = $data1['file_name']; //name of  img

            }

        /**End uploading img**/
    }
```

The images are getting uploaded but they are getting uplaoded to same folder. Can anyone please tell how i can make the files get saved in seperate folders

Comment: the image is uploaded in the file flolder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the second load , you need to initialiaze the loaded library because the load method don't initialize it  :

```
$this->upload->initialize($config2);
```